# how to create Google App Engine Project with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, gradle

A I'm new to Google App Engine and even I have Spring tool suite with gradle plugin installed, I facing difficulty . I want to know what the process ,how to implement ,if any sample basic project to implement can anybody help me .Even I have Goggled but getting get the doc and but when I'm trying to implement getting errors,unable to create a sample project any suggestion with code is appreciated

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 12):

Here is my setup for the appengine guestbook sample

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}


appengine {
    httpPort = 8085

    appcfg {
        email = 'you@gmail.com'
        passIn = true

        logs {
            severity = 1
            outputFile = file('mylogs.txt')
        }

        app {
            id = 'guestbook'
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.properties (in project root)

```
systemProp.appengine.sdk.root = /Users/<me>/Documents/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.4
```

Create a webapp directory in your project's "src/main" folder and copy the files from the sample webapp directory there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd check out the docs for Google's offical [Gradle AppEngine plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin), which also has a small example. SpringSource Tool Suite is irrelevant here. If you hit any problems, post a concrete question that explains the problem in detail, along with all output you get.

Comment: Thank you for response, I'm already following the the Doc.but I'm  getting some problem when trying to implement.can I directly Import it in STS this project.

Comment: There is no way around fixing these problems, and STS won't help here.